# Windows 7 Domain Account cannot read/write inside AppData folder

Tags: inno-setup, windows-7-x64, windowsdomainaccount

I am creating an installer with InnoSetup. My program requires that I be able to read and write to files as it reads data from my hardware device that is connected over IPv4. I also write to files as I am creating content within my program. I am having issues on a Windows 7 Professional 64bit machine that has a domain account. It is not allowing some .exe files within my program to open as necessary. The .exe files that need to open are reading and writing data from the files to which I have created content with the main exe of my entire program. The error that comes up is when I click a button in one program that will open another .exe file. The error reads *Failed to set data for ""*. It seems as though the argument is being passed for my button link, but the link becomes null where it is trying to open "" file, which does not have a pathway. There appears to be some permission on the file that is rendering its location as unreadable, thus giving the failed to open "" location.

I have setup my installation file with the following flags that I believe should be necessary to allow read/write access in Windows 7.

```
[setup]
DefaultDirName={localappdata}\{#MyAppName} 
; to install to localappdata folder of local user

[Dirs]
Name: "{app}" ; Permissions: users-modify users-full
; to allow the user to have read/write permission of all files within the installation     folder. This should not be necessary because localappdata should already     have read/write permissions.
```

This works fine on other machines that have only local user accounts. However, on the same computer that I am having trouble with, I have tried logging in as a local user account and I still find the same errors.

What am I missing to allow the program to read/write to all files within my installation folder, located in c://user/domainaccountaddress/appdata/local/my program directory?

I'm quite new to this, all advice is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be because you use localappdata, try using appdata instead. Localappdata might cause problems when you have roaming users.

Comment: I've tried both options and it isn't running properly. I went back to Program Files install. I have found that if I right click and "Run As Administrator" each time I open the program, it runs OK. If I simply double-click the program without the added "Run As Admin" the program does not function correctly. When I add the flag "Run This Program As Administrator" by right clicking and choosing the box, the program runs OK. I feel like this is a fundamental flaw in the way the program is designed and I need to have our vendor fix it. I was hoping to find a way around it with my installation file.